# What is the Internet Explorer Plug-in name of the IBM Notes Browser Plugin?

Tags: lotus-domino, browser-plugin

I am trying to detect if the plug-in is installed using the msieDetect function from this page at [webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins](http://webdevwonders.com/detecting-browser-plugins/)

I can detect the iNotes plug-in using "dwa9.dwa9" but I have not been able to find the right name to use for the "IBM Notes Browser Plug-in".